# Retain system color scheme when running without GUI

Tags: themes, colors, gui-emacs

I'm typically running `emacs -nw`: problem is that Emacs overrides terminal (bash) color scheme and uses it's own default one which is in some cases unreadable.

I would like emacs to use default colors which are defined in my terminal "app". I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04 and this is when this started happening.

Was looking, couldn't find an answer anywhere.

```
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)
```

seems to fix readability problem, however it's not 100% what I would like

Comment: You could try conditionally setting your theme when `(display-graphic-p)` is `t`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, would you care to elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Can you explain why it is not 100% what you want? Please specify just what you want, and say what is still missing.

Comment: It's not because emacs still overrides my terminal colors: ie if I set all my terminal font colors to red, I want emacs to display only red letters

Comment: If that's the case, you probably want to disable `font-lock-mode`.

Comment: Another approach could be [this](https://github.com/cqql/xresources-theme) which would base your emacs theme on the X settings.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to accomplish this is to set the theme only when you start Emacs with a graphical frame. This isn't the most robust solution, as it won't work with Emacs ran as a daemon, which would cause trouble when you have both text and graphical frames at the same time, and if you just start a daemon, it doesn't claim it's graphical.

Anyway, you can try adding something like this to your init file:

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  (load-theme 'my-theme t))
```

Where `my-theme` should be replaced with the name of a theme you want to use.

Comment: thanks for your answer, will try this and report back asap